# Hide Inner Div Using jQuery

Tags: jquery

```
    <a href="#"> Link1  </a>  
    <div id="parent">
         <div id="child1">
                    Here is the Child One
         </div>
         <div id="child2">
                    Here is the Child Two
         </div>
    </div>
```

How can i hide child1 div using jquery ?

**UPDATE**

I want to hide child1 on click of Link1

Comment: which link..??? i can not see link..

Comment: Please consider my edit as per your edited question

Comment: show markup for the link..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*If you want to hide the first Inner child inside the div:-*

```
$('#link1ID').click(function(){        
    $('div#parent div:first').hide();    
});
```

*If you want to hide using child ID:-*

```
 $('#link1ID').click(function(){            
        $('div#parent div#child1').hide();        
 });
```

Comment: Thank you very much ,It will hide only first child , what if i want to hide by child id?

Answer (score 2):

why use jQuery?

CSS

```
 #child1{
   display: none;
 }
```

or if you really want to use jQuery

`$("#child1").hide();`

If you want to hide on click:
Because you are using IDs in your markup, this is really simple

```
$("#parent").click(function() {
   $("#child1").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$('div#parent > div#child1').hide();
```

Above for hiding direct child of `#parent`.

**For Click**

```
$('YOURLINK').on('click',function()
{
    $('div#parent > div#child1').hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try with

```
$("#child1").hide();
```

or you can try like

```
$("#child1").css('display','none');
```

based on your edited question it should be like

```
$("#link1").click(function(e){
     e.preventDefault();
     $("#child1").hide();
});
```

and see jquery functionalities in http://jquery.com/

and see jquery selectors in http://api.jquery.com/selector/

Answer (score 1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
     $("#link1").on('click',function(){
         $("#child1").hide();
     });
});
```

**Same for child2** .

Answer (score 0):

this will hide child1 onclick link1 and child2 onclick link2

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/pintu31/Smx4k/)**

```
$('a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    $(this).closest('div').hide();
});
```

if you want to hide child1 onclick of any link under parent div

```
$('a').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault()
    $(this).parentsUntil('parent').find('#child1').hide();
});
```

**HTML**

```
<div id="parent">
     <div id="child1">
         <a href="#">link1</a>
     </div>
     <div id="child2">
         <a href="#">link2</a>
     </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just select and hide the children, like this:

```
$("#parent").children().hide();
```

Then, select and show/hide/whatever the children whenever you want.